# SharePoint 2013, make a vanity dns name point to site collection

Tags: dns

Ok, This is driving me crazy. This is not the normal Alt. Access Mapping. Project manager wants a host based site collection and the URL looks like this. dev.na.ourdomain.com/facility/a1. This was created and works fine. This is the web app url just so you have the information. webapp.na.ourdomain.com.

He wants a vanity URL so the users do not have to type in the long domain. He wants the users to be able to put in dev.a1.na.ourdomain.com and go right to the host based site collection dev.na.ourdomain.com/facility/a1.

I have went over everything in my head and it is a completely different URL than what the Web Application is set to. I am at a loss. If someone can please help me out with this one. If you can tell me what I am missing to make this work or if I am right and this is never going to work and a note why it wont.

Comment: so you create the HNSC on this url dev.na.ourdomain.com/facility/a1. Now you want to access this site using this dev.a1.na.ourdomain.com. is it right?  did you set the url of the HSNC using the set-spsiteurl other than the default zone

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create a dns record for dev.a1.na.ourdomain.com and point to SharePoint's IIS, and then do your aam or binding from there?

Comment: I have added a DNS entry for dev.a1.na.ourdomain.com to point to the WFE server. and I get a 404 error.understandable because WFE does not know what to do with the request since there is no web app or site collection with that name on the app server. I am running Enterprise with 3 servers at the moment. front end, app and sql.

Comment: I don't feel confident explaining how to set up aam from here. You want to be sure that you don't overwrite the entry site collection at webapp.na.ourdomain.com. Someone else might be able to assist you

Comment: The jist of the story goes, that you want to set up Alternate Accessmappings so that the Internal URL dev.a1.na.ourdomain.com points to dev.na.ourdomain.com/facility/a1.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the SC and recreated it with the new url. Made life easier.